# How to create own brand color style using material3?

Tags: android, colors, material-design, material-components-android, android-jetpack-compose-material3

The Material 3 color theming system can be used to create a color scheme that reflects your brand or style as per material 3 guidelines.

Ref:
https://m3.material.io/libraries/mdc-android/color-theming

My brand color is RED, **how to create a Light/Dark Theme Baseline Using The Color Theming System.**  as per material 3 guidelines.

**Is there any online color code builder?**

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yeah you can try material theme builder.

Here take a look : [Material Theme Builder](https://m3.material.io/theme-builder#/custom)

[image]

Comment: you can pick colors bro, just go to custom color tab and click on the primary color on the leftmost side, the color picker will show up.

Comment: you can also pick a wallpaper of your choice and fetch color from it

Comment: There is no any Kotlin code for this right? I would like to generate at least the primary dark color based on a given color (primary light)